# MetaMask mobile token transfer invalid amount error

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, metamask

I was creating a web3js token transfer transaction and sending it to MetaMask mobile. It was working flawlessly before. But now there is a problem called invalid amount. While working in the browser, TrustWallet, etc., I only get this warning on MetaMask mobile. I tried sending in normal format instead of hex. But nothing changed. How can I solve this? Below is the tx example I created.

```
amount = Utils.toHex(amount, (await this.getDecimals()));

let data = this.contract.transfer.getData(to, amount, {from: this.multiChain.connectedAccount});
            
let gas = await this.multiChain.getEstimateGas({
    to: this.address,
    from: this.multiChain.connectedAccount,
    value: '0x0',
    data
});

this.multiChain.connector.sendTransaction([{
    to: this.address,
    from: this.multiChain.connectedAccount,
    value: '0x0',
    gas,
    data
}])
.then((transactionId) => {
    resolve(transactionId);
})
.catch((error) => {
    reject(error);
});
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you resolved it yet?

Comment: Same issue here. Only native token transfers are working on desktop and mobile... erc20 transfers work only on desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:
https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile/issues/3999

add gasPrice

```
const  gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();

this.multiChain.connector.sendTransaction([{
    to: this.address,
    from: this.multiChain.connectedAccount,
    value: '0x0',
    gas,
    gasPrice, 
    data
}])
}).then((transaction) => {
    ...
})
```